# How to bin groupeby counts in pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

After days of research I am stuck.  Am new to Python/Pandas.  Trying to convert data analysis from multiple excel sheets to a python solution.

I am calculating the learning curve for new people in particular skills.  To do this I have the following dataset:

- COMM_ID - unique numeric identifier per communication
- SKILL - the category of communication - text
- LOGIN - login for the person - text
- OFFERS - was a survey sent, 1 or 0
- RESPONSES - was there a response to the survey, 1 or 0
- NOs - was the response negative, 1 or 0

In the below I build the dataframe, sort by SKill, Login and then COMM_ID.  The COMM_ID puts it in chronological order.  Then I groupby Skill and Login.

How would I take the dataframe and cut the data into two dataframes? One for responses and the other for Nos, for each combination of skill and login with bins of 50 increments.  Need to look at each segment of 50 COMM_IDs (50, 100, 150) and count how many 1s are in each of those segement.  This would be for every skill/login combo.  The SUM of the 1s would then go in the dataframe per the bins.

I have tried variations of pandas.cut to no success.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import odbc
from pandas import DataFrame

#Call ODBC connection
db = odbc.odbc('HID')

# SQL Query to get data
sqlRRAgentSkill = """ 
SELECT
COMM_ID, 
SKILL, 
LOGIN, 
OFFERS, 
RESPONSES,
NOs
FROM 
2013_2014;
"""

#Call SQL 
RRdata = pd.read_sql_query(sqlRRAgentSkill,db)

#Sort data
RRDataSorted = RRdata.sort_index(ascending=[True,True,True], by = ['SKILL', 'LOGIN', 'COMM_ID'])

# Group data by Skill and Login
grouped = RRDataSorted.groupby(['SKILL', 'LOGIN'])

# Bins for contacts
startBin = 0
stopBin = 1000
incrementBin = 50
sortbins = np.arange(startBin, stopBin + incrementBin, incrementBin)
```

Comment: and the question is?..

Comment: sorry it was late when I wrote this.... I edited the question.  "How would I take the dataframe and cut the data into two dataframes? One for responses and the other for Nos, for each combination of skill and login with bins of 50 increments."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Not sure if it is the cleanest way but it worked.

Built function to add a 'COUNT' column to the groups:

```
#Add count row to the groups
def addcount(x):
    x['COUNTS'] = range(1,x.COMM_ID.count()+1)
    return x
```

Applied that to the groups:

```
#Insert count row into all groups and recombine
RRData = grouped.apply(addcount)
```

Made a 'BINS' column and used cut to group them:

```
#Insert BINS column
RRData['BINS'] = pd.cut(RRData.COUNTS,sortBins, labels = binLabels)
```

Used pivot_table twice to make two binned dataframes:

```
#Pivot to produce No's Bin table
Nos = pivot_table(RRData, values = 'NOs', index = ['SKILL', 'LOGIN'], columns = 'BINS', aggfunc = np.sum)
#Pivot to produce Responses Bin table
Responses = pivot_table(RRData, values = 'RESPONSES', index = ['SKILL', 'LOGIN'], columns = 'BINS', aggfunc = np.sum)
```

To go beyond my question, I then created the a metric derived third df and then did an index reset to eliminate the multi-index:

```
#Create RR dataframep
rr = Nos/Responses
#Reset dataframe index
rr = rr.reset_index()
Responses = Responses.reset_index()
Nos = Nos.reset_index()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean indexing to filter on the value of a dataframe column like so:

```
no = df[df['NOs'] == 1]
yes = df[df['NOs'] == 0]
```

There are lots of ways to apply this to your problem, but if I understand your approach correctly -- a straightforward application that follows your structure would be something like this:

```
for _, group in grouped:
    for row in sortbins:
        data = group[row: row+50]
        # filter data here
```

You can read more about indexing and selecting here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html